# Regular expression matching [^a-z] or $

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with string regex matching a word in a sentence accounting for punctuation and the end of the line. My attempt fails for the end of line case.

The following examples evaluate as I need:

```
>>> print bool(re.search('test[^a-z]','test!'.lower()))
True
>>> print bool(re.search('test[^a-z]','test aaa'.lower()))
True
>>> print bool(re.search('test[^a-z]','testaaa'.lower()))
False
```

However the end of line case evaluates `False`:

```
>>> print bool(re.search('test[^a-z]','test'.lower()))
False
```

The end of line character `$` isn't in the set `a-z` so locigal I thought this case would also evaluate `True`. How can I handle this in `regex`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
'test(?![a-z])'
```

Or an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
'test([^a-z]|$)'
```